# Import project generated by gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, m2eclipse, gwt-maven-plugin

i followed the instruction of [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/), generated then imported the project below,

1) Generate the project

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin \
   -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.0

...

Define value for property 'groupId': : org.codehaus.mojo
Define value for property 'artifactId': : gwt-maven-plugin-sample
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
Define value for property 'package':  org.codehaus.mojo: : 
Define value for property 'module': : Sample 

...
```

2) Check the generated POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin-sample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.5.0</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>i18n</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>Sample.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <i18nMessagesBundle>org.codehaus.mojo.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

3) Check the generated project

```
gwt-maven-plugin-sample/
├── .classpath
├── pom.xml
├── .project
├── SampleTest-dev.launch
├── SampleTest-prod.launch
├── .settings
│   ├── com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.prefs
│   ├── com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs
│   ├── com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.prefs
│   ├── .jsdtscope
│   ├── org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│   ├── org.eclipse.wst.common.component
│   ├── org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
│   ├── org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
│   └── org.maven.ide.eclipse.prefs
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── org
│   │   │       └── codehaus
│   │   │           └── mojo
│   │   │               ├── client
│   │   │               │   ├── GreetingService.java
│   │   │               │   └── Sample.java
│   │   │               ├── server
│   │   │               │   └── GreetingServiceImpl.java
│   │   │               └── shared
│   │   │                   └── FieldVerifier.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── org
│   │   │       └── codehaus
│   │   │           └── mojo
│   │   │               ├── client
│   │   │               │   ├── Messages_fr.properties
│   │   │               │   └── Messages.properties
│   │   │               └── Sample.gwt.xml
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── Sample.css
│   │       ├── Sample.html
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── web.xml
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── org
│       │       └── codehaus
│       │           └── mojo
│       │               └── client
│       │                   └── GwtTestSample.java
│       └── resources
│           └── org
│               └── codehaus
│                   └── mojo
│                       └── SampleJUnit.gwt.xml
└── target
    └── generated-sources
        └── gwt
            └── org
                └── codehaus
                    └── mojo

33 directories, 26 files
```

4) On Eclipse, choose "Import Existing Project to Workspace"

[image: imported eclipse project]

5) According to the instruction of [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/), the imported project should have  resulted in the project structure similar to below,

[image: expected eclipse project]

In the end by our comparing 4) to 5), the problem in sight seems that no maven dependencies were added by the import at all, in other words, the generated project was not validated as a maven project. So, what's wrong with the steps above and the configuration below?

```
gwt-maven-plugin 2.5.0
m2e 1.2.0.20120903-1050
eclipse 3.7.2
maven 3.0.4
```

**@EDIT**

Ran "mvn gwt:run" successfully, but failed to launch `DevMode` by `GWT Eclipse Plugin`,

[image: gwt devmode error]

**@EDIT 2**

Referring to the link from `@Sachin Shekhar R`, i've looked into [the official GWT Wiki: working with maven](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven), followed the instruction and tested [DynaTable RequestFactory sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/dynatablerf/). Great, it does work!

Unfortunately, the Wiki echoes that `gwt-maven-plugin` does have issues with the `archetype` in use.

Comment: Can you post what error you are facing along with error log or screenshot. Example - Maven compilation failed or devmode launch failed?

Comment: Thx, pls check the error above. The obvious problem to me is no maven dependencies added by the import at all.

Comment: Well as the error states, is the `gwt-servlet.jar` on the classpath? Also, GWT-2.0.4 is ancient, you should upgrade to 2.5.

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup, dependency management is supposed the job of `gwt-maven-plugin` and `m2e`.

Comment: I know that, still you're getting that error, right? In any case, you have a dep on 2.0.4 and your GWT plugin version is 2.5.0 - that's where you should look. Is the project actually a GWT product in Eclipse's eyes?

Comment: GPE launch in maven peoject is able to pick up from target\<project>\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-servlet.jar . @sof - Point your GPE to GWT 2.5 as per Anders suggestion and then do mvn clean install and try again.

Comment: I'd like to see if `gwt-maven-plugin` together with `m2e` works out of box as supposed to do. Manual hack on the problem brings no added value on their own. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

gwt-maven-plugin 2.5.0 works best with GWT 2.5.0. The statement Ran "mvn gwt:run" successfully, but failed to launch DevMode by GWT Eclipse Plugin is a bit confusing.

I also noticed that in your case -

1) The generated pom file in indicates 2.5.0 and eclipse screenshot indicates 2.0.4. This might because your GPE is pointing to GWT 2.0.4 and overriding the pom files directive.

2) If you are using maven gwt:run then GWT Eclipse Plugin is irrelevant. The dev mode gets launched **`either`** by

- a) `mvn gwt:run`
- b) by GWT Eclipse Plugin when you right click on project and select `Debug As` -> `Web Application`

3) Maven dependencies are being shown in the screenshot you have shared. Can you expand it and verify which jars are being picked up.

`Edit` - 
You can try some additional troubleshooting tips from with http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

My guess would be the configuration **@** `Project properties, Google > Web Application, the "This project has a WAR directory"`

Comment: Sorry for something obscure. The pointer to GWT 2.0.4 from the picture on 5) above is not the result of my import (it's on 4), but the outdated description by `gwt-maven-plugin`. The correct GWT version is 2.5.0 as you guess. `mvn gwt:run` works via CLI, but `Run as -> Web App` fails via GPE. i need the latter to work, too.

Comment: Thanks for the link to this `GWT Wiki`.